# PHP 8 get_class returns cached class name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use a Pipeline design pattern which is provided by Laravel. I am guarding the pipeline step based on the class name of the current step. However, the reflection is broken for whatever reason.

I am sharing my class structure in case this problem is beyond reflection.

---

Each step in the pipeline should inherit this abstract class so it can dynamically apply steps based on a guard.

`PipelineStep`

```php
abstract class PipelineStep
{
  public function handle($content, Closure $next)
  {
    $builder = next($content);

    // always returns first class name of child class
    $cls = get_class($this); 
    
    return $this->apply($builder);
  }
  
  protected abstract function apply($builder);

}
```

So now each step has its own reusable class.

```php
class Step1 extends PipelineStep
{
   protected function apply ($builder)
   {
     // do stuff
   }
}

class Step2 extends PipelineStep
{
   protected function apply ($builder)
   {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

Finally, to put it all together, I specify the pipeline on the model class. However, the pipeline will never run Step2 because the reflection is broken. Instead, it will run Step1 twice.

```php
class MyModel {
  use HasPipeline;

  protected static $steps = [
    Step1::class,
    Step2::class
  ];
}

$myModelInstance->getPipelineResult(); // runs step1 twice.
```

---

So, why is the class reflection not working in this design pattern? Is something being cached in PHP 8? Is this a Laravel problem? Or is this problem caused by something else entirely?

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show us a [mcve] - the fact that you're using a Trait is probably irrelevant, so you can simplify that; you've defined `PipelineStep` but inherited from `Filter`; and you've got functions like `someGuard` and `someResult` which could just be comments if you want to illustrate the idea. It also took me a while to find which line you were saying was broken, because there's no actual Reflection in this code, and the comment about the problem you've identified is right in the middle of your question, rather than at the start or end.

Comment: What do you mean there is no reflection? Is `get_class()` not how to get the child's class name?

Comment: When you mentioned "reflection", I assumed you meant [the PHP Reflection API](https://www.php.net/reflection), so was looking for that in your code. I can see how `get_class` could be described as a kind of "reflection", but it would be clearer to just say "get_class doesn't return the class name I'm expecting". The more minimal and correct you can make your example (make sure you've actually **run** the code you show us, not just edited in your browser), the less confusing that will be.

Comment: What do your `use` statements look like? Could you have possibly imported a class as the wrong name (e.g. imported `Step1` as `PipelineStep` in Step2's file)?